Clarify path-lifting property for principal G-bundles?
Let me start out by saying that this is kind of a duplicate of
Path lifting in principal bundles
Unique existence of horizontal lifts in Principal $G$-bundles
and
Path lifting property induced by local triviality of a principle G bundle.
However, after reading all of these answers, I have come away more confused than before.
Let $P\xrightarrow{\pi}M$ be a smooth principal $G$-bundle ($G$ a Lie group). Let $\gamma:I\rightarrow M$ be a smooth curve, and I want to know if I can lift $\gamma:I\rightarrow M$ to a smooth $\tilde{\gamma}:I\rightarrow M$.

From the comments of the first question, I have come away thinking that there is no such theorem that says "There exists a smooth lift of a smooth path $\gamma:I\rightarrow M$ by a principal $G$-bundle $\pi:P\rightarrow M$".
But principal bundles are fibrations, are they not? So they should have a homotopy lifting property? Or is this just not true at all in the smooth category and smooth fiber bundles don't have anything like a smooth homotopy lifting property? (Are they "smooth fibrations" in some other sense?)
Furthermore, why can't I just construct a smooth lift by just taking a smooth global section of the pullback bundle $\gamma^*P\xrightarrow{\pi^*} I$ (which is trivial since $I$ is contracible)?

Again from the first and third question, I wonder how the proof of existence and uniqueness of horizontal lifts can proceed if all I can construct is a continuous lift $\tilde{\gamma}:I\rightarrow P$ of $\gamma$. In this case, even though, as a commenter points out, I can ensure that the horizontal lift $\gamma^H(t) = \tilde{\gamma}(t)\cdot g(t)$ is smooth, I can't, for instance, write down the ODE that $\gamma^H$ satisfies because it involves differentials of $\tilde{\gamma}$ and $g(t)$ (where $g:I\rightarrow G$), which might not be smooth at least at some points.


I find this even more troubling since every proof I have read of this theorem (existence and uniqueness of horizontal lifted paths) starts out by just saying "pick any lift of $\gamma$" without any caveat that no smooth lift need exist...

Homotopy theory alone only guarantees continuous lifts. It might help to edit the question to clarify your notation and explicitly state hypotheses. Particularly, is $M$ a smooth manifold, $G$ a Lie group, and $P$ a smooth principal $G$-bundle? Is $P$ equipped with a smooth connection?

I have tried to add some clarification. Yes, you're correct about all my notation. I suppose I can assume that $P$ is equipped with a smooth connection since we can always equip one.

Instead of reading comments (of possibly questionable quality) you should consider reading, say, Steenrod's book on fiber bundles. Yes, there is always a smooth lift. You can even find a canonical lift once you fix a connection on your bundle.

@MoisheKohan Steenrod's book doesn't seem to talk about smooth bundles at all, and smoothness is my issue here.

He does........

"The Topology of Fibre Bundles" by Normal Steenrod? Do you have a page number for anything about smooth lifts or horizontal lifts? (Maybe the version I am seeing online is old?)

@MoisheKohan I have now looked very thoroughly through Steenrod's book and I am not sure what you are referring to still. Are you sure you aren't thinking of a different book maybe?

I'm not at expert at all so I could very likely be wrong, but maybe this is helpful for you.
Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\pi:P\to M$ be a $G$-principal bundle equipped with a connection $\omega\in\Omega^1(P,\mathfrak{g})$ (here everything is smooth).
Let $\gamma:I\to M$ be a smooth curve.
We want to find an horizontal lifting of $\gamma$:
$$\gamma^h:I\to P.$$
One can find $t_0,\dots,t_n\in I$ such that $$\text{Im}(\gamma|_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]})\subset U_i$$
for some trivializing opens $U_i\subset M$.
Now on these opens $\gamma|_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]}$ lifts to a smooth map
$$\gamma^h_i=(\gamma|_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]},g):[t_i,t_{i+1}]\to U_i\times G,$$
where $g:[t_i,t_{i+1}]\to G$.
With some work one can find an ODE for $g$ such that the solution makes $\gamma_i^h$ into an horizontal lifting of $\gamma|_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]}$ (these lecture notes may be helpful).
Take initial conditions of these ODE such that the liftings $\gamma_i^h$ glue to a continous map $\gamma^h:I\to P$.
Now because of the horizontality condition on the liftings $\gamma^h_i$, the one-sided derivatives of $\gamma_i^h:[t_i,t_{i+1}]\to P$ and $\gamma_{i+1}^h:[t_{i+1},t_{i+2}]\to P$ concide at $t_{i+1}$, so $\gamma^h$ is also smooth.
